# GraphQL subscriptions or RabbitMQ Message Queuing

Tags: react-native, graphql

I'm building a chat & notifications server based on NestJS & I'm worried about the best method to build the server to handle a minimum of 10K users/month. Please I need help. ( It's a react-native app client ).
I intend to use FCM & APNS to push notifications to users but about chat, no idea what to do.